# How to add content to Angular Material Tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to put tabs in my toolbar w/ angular material.

I found a great example:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="center end">
    <div flex flex-sm="100" flex-gt-sm="95" flex-gt-md="80" layout="column">
        <span flex></span>
        <md-tabs  md-stretch-tabs="always" class="md-primary">
            <md-tab id="tab1" aria-controls="Tab 1">
                <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab id="tab2" aria-controls="Tab 2">
                <md-tab-label>Tab 2</md-tab-label>
            </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Works perfect, except that I am not sure how to add content.

If I put an `<md-tab-body>` tag inside the `<md-tab>` tag then the toolbar expands and that new content is within the toolbar, which I don't want.  I want the tab content to be below the toolbar.

I just started to play around with angular material so I feel like I am missing something fundamental.

Looking at the tab docs it seems like used tabs with external content might useful, however the docs do not go into how one might do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should help you, I am new to this But by reading doc code [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.tabs/directive/mdTabs) ,I found that the content can be added using `md-tab-body`. So I tried that you can see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwqrBo) . I have added the `md-tab-body` just below `md-tab-label`. Hope this helps you. Thank you for showing me such a nice designing material.

Adding my code here:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="center end">
<div flex flex-sm="100" flex-gt-sm="95" flex-gt-md="80" layout="column">
    <span flex></span>
    <md-tabs  md-stretch-tabs="always" class="md-primary">
        <md-tab id="tab1" aria-controls="Tab 1">
            <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
      <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
    </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab id="tab2" aria-controls="Tab 2">
            <md-tab-label>Tab 2</md-tab-label>
          <md-tab-body>
      <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
    </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div></md-toolbar>
```

**Edit1**
ok.But I think your question didn't mention anything about the color.Those can be done with css too. Now I have updated the codepen and you can see that [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvgavp) or [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwqrBo) or this with other color [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpdBOp). Hope this helps you. and If this helps you please rate my answer.

**Edit2**
Ok.After searching more on web I found that something called `md-selected` can be used to keep track of which tab is selected. and then Based `on` the value of that index I used `ng-switch-when` the value is that index. It is just similar to normal `Switch-case` statements. I also removed that css so the it becomes more clear. You can see the solution [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpdBOp).I hope my solution is clear to you. I tried to keep it as simple as possible. Thank you.

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid.  See how in your example the content is within the blue toolbar.  I want the tabs in the blue toolbar, but the content in the white portion below the nav bar.

Comment: The content with the body of that tags still lies within the toolbar.  I want the tab content to live outside the toolbar.  In your example you can see how the brown toolbar color still wraps everything.

Comment: @lostintranslation Thanks for making it clear. I have edited my answer Please see **Edit2**. Hope this time it helps you. Let me know If I am still wrong I will try again. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @govindpatel
i have used your code and facing below issue

angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=tabsDemoDynamicHeig…FC%3A%2FUsers%2FKH1983%2FDesktop%2FWebEaxmples%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)

can you please let me know , what i am missing

Comment: ok. without the code I can't guess anything. Feels like you might have missed something probably check your script statement. Something close to that.
But how come you are getting the error in `angular.min.js:6`. Please look at your code carefully once again. and if you are still getting the error. Please also see the codepen which I have provided and compare with your code. If you are still facing the problem, please do paste the code in jsfiddle or codepen, like I did.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late but here you go...

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>.intermediate { background:lightgray; }</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
      <div ng-controller="TabCtrl" layout="column">      
        <md-toolbar layout="column" layout-align="end">
          <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
            <md-tab label="tab1" ng-click="tabClicked('tab1')"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="tab2" ng-click="tabClicked('tab2')"></md-tab>
            <md-tab label="tab3" ng-click="tabClicked('tab3')"></md-tab>
          </md-tabs>
        </md-toolbar>
        <div layout="row" layout-padding class="intermediate">Intermediate element1</div>
        <div layout="row" layout-padding class="intermediate">Intermediate element2</div>
        <div layout="row" layout-padding class="intermediate">Intermediate element3</div>      
        <md-content flex layout-fill layout-padding ng-bind-html="tabContent">
          <!-- tab content gets injected here -->        
        </md-content>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('TabCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {

  // manually update associated tab content
  $scope.tabClicked = function(tab) {
  switch (tab) {
    case 'tab1':
      $scope.tabContent = $sce.trustAsHtml('<strong class="md-display-1">TAB1 CONTENT</strong>');
      break;
    case 'tab2':
      $scope.tabContent = $sce.trustAsHtml('<em class="md-display-2">TAB2 CONTENT</em>');
      break;
    case 'tab3':
      $scope.tabContent = $sce.trustAsHtml('<div class="md-display-4">TAB3 CONTENT</div>');
      break;
    }
  }

  // Initialize default content
  $scope.tabClicked('tab1');
}]);
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nub340/pen/RaOgGm)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it for Angular Material

In the LeashedIn Demo App from "Angular Material 2 Jeremy Elbourn and Kara Erickson" presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0q9FOeEELPY

They use this code:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>TAB 1 LABEL</template>
        <template md-tab-content>TAB 1 CONTENT</template>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab>
        <template md-tab-label>TAB 2 LABEL</template>
        <template md-tab-content>TAB 2 CONTENT</template>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
```

But it did not work for me!

This is what worked for me:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="TAB 1 LABEL">
        TAB 1 CONTENT
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="TAB 2 LABEL">
        TAB 2 CONTENT
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Source:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/README.md

Comment: the OP requested for an `angularjs material` version, not `angular material2`.

Comment: Also note that there are more docs [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/tabs.md)